# Cassandra java driver - high latency while extracting data with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra

I can see a strange behavior with datastax cassandra driver (3.0). I've created a new cluster, then I've started a set of threads using the same cluster object. If I keep threads to 1 or 2, I see an avg extraction time of 5ms, but if I increase threads to 60, extraction time increase to 200ms (per single thread). Strange thing is that, if I let the 60 threads app running and I start on the same machine another process with only 1 threads, extraction time for that single threaded app is again 5ms. So it seems something related to client. I've repeated the same tests many times to avoid the cache cold start problem.
Here is how cluster object is configured:

```
    PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
    poolingOptions
        .setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,  parallelism, parallelism+20)
        .setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, parallelism, parallelism+20)
        .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768)
        .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2000);

    this.cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(nodes)
            .withRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
            .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L))
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().build()))
            .withCompression(Compression.LZ4)
            .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
            .withProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.V4)
            .build();
```

Does anyone have experienced the same problem? It seems a client configuration issue. Maybe some additional missing configuration for Netty?

**UPDATE 1**
What application is doing is extracting chunk of data using a query like:

```
select * from table where id=? and ts>=? and ts<?
```

So I have 60 threads that are extracting those data in parallel. id is the partition key. Every query is executed by the thread as:

```
//Prepare statement
PreparedStatement stmt = ... get the prepared statment cached
BoundStatement bstmt = stmt.bind(...)
//Execute query
long te1 = System.nanoTime();       
ResultSet rs = this.session.execute(bstmt);
long te2 = System.nanoTime();
//Fetch...
Iterator<Row> iterator = rs.iterator();
while (!rs.isExhausted() && iterator.hasNext()) { .... }
```

session is one and shared cross all threads. What I'm measuring is the avg time of the session.execute() method call.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 2**
Here is schema definition

```
CREATE TABLE d_t (
    id bigint,
    xid bigint,
    ts timestamp,
    avg double,
    ce double,
    cg double,
    p double,
    w double,
    c double,
    sum double,
    last double,
    max double,
    min double,
    p75 double,
    p90 double,
    p95 double,
    squad double,
    sumq double,
    wavg double,
    weight double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id), xid, ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (xid DESC, ts DESC)
and  compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} 
and gc_grace_seconds=86400
and caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition':'36000' }
and min_index_interval = 2
and max_index_interval = 20;
```

**UPDATE 3**
Also tried with

```
.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 1)
.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 1)
```

with no changes

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I think it will depend on what your code is doing.  Can you share an example?

With regards to increased latency, how are you measuring this?  Based on your statement:

> Strange thing is that, if I let the 60 threads app running and I start on the same machine another process with only 1 threads, extraction time for that single threaded app is again 5ms.

60 concurrent requests really isn't all too much and in general, you shouldn't need to do a thread-per-request using the datastax java driver.  You can achieve high throughput with a single application thread as the netty event loop group the driver uses will do most of the work.

The native protocol C* uses allows many requests per connection.  As you have configured here, each connection is maxed out to 32768 concurrent requests.   In reality, you don't really need to touch this configuration at all, as the default (1000 requests per connection) is sensible as in practice C* is not going to process more than `native_transport_max_threads` from cassandra.yaml (128 default) at a time and queue up the rest.

Because of this, you do not need many connections for each host.  The default of 1 core connection per host should be more than enough for 60 concurrent requests.  Increasing the number of connections per host won't do much for you and in profiling I've found diminishing returns beyond 8 connections per host with high throughputs (thousands of concurrent requests) and throughput getting worse past 16 connections per host, though your mileage may vary based on environment.

With all that said, I would recommend not configuring `PoolingOptions` beyond the default, other than maybe setting core and max to 8 for scenarios where you are trying to achieve higher throughputs (> 10k requests/sec).

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question with an example of what application is doing. Regards

Comment: Before I get into that,  how large are your result sets?   (number of columns per row, how many rows per query?)

Comment: Typically from 700 to 800 rows with 15 columns per row

Comment: Added also schema definition

Comment: Did you geta  change to review it? Thanks!